# Expected value of two independent binomial variables

Tags: probability

Find E[(X-Y)^2], where X and Y are two independent binomial random variables with n = 3, p = 0.4.

I simply rewrote it as E[ X^2 - 2XY + Y^2 ], but can you assume that E[X^2] = E[X] x E[X]? If so, as the expected value of both are equal will be easy to find but can someone explain to me why you can or cannot do E[X^2] = E[X] x E[X]?

Thank you.

EDIT: Ok I think the way to solve this is to use the equation Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 but conceptually is it correct to do what my initial thought was?

Comment: If your initial thought would be correct then the variance of $X$ would be $0$. It is not correct. To find a counterexample you only need some rv having a positive variance. There are plenty. Ever rv that is non-constant has a positive variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(x^2)$ is not equal to $E(x)*E(x)$, you can find this value known it is a binomial distribution.

Check this document:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m302/binomial.pdf

Basically apply $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ and then $E(X^2)=Var(X)+E(X)^2$

If you want $E(X)^2=E(X^2)$, you need to have $Var(X)$ equal to 0, which is wrong.